# Keyerror when the value is present

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a list into a dictionary while extracting and assigning one element of the list as ley and another as values. The list looks like

```
todos = [{"general":{"imgUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQEj3RU2C8iLyA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0?e=1568246400&v=beta&t=TBI7KQkcTxdx8Cwbe9PQnP3dkbEc9SI1lLsRGYylS8g","fullName":"A. Valerie Mirko","headline":"General Counsel at North American Securities Administrators Association (NASAA)","company":"North American Securities Administrators Association (NASAA)","school":"The George Washington University Law School","location":"Washington, District Of Columbia","connections":"500+ connections","profileUrl":"https://www.linkedin.com/in/a-valerie-mirko-b856b510/","connectionDegree":"3rd","vmid":"ACoAAAI9K1UBjo3KEOpu_YEN3edB_0UdyvmHOb0","linkedinSalesNavigatorUrl":"https://www.linkedin.com/sales/people/ACoAAAI9K1UBjo3KEOpu_YEN3edB_0UdyvmHOb0,name","description":"","firstName":"A.","lastName":"Valerie Mirko"},"jobs":[{"companyName":"North American Securities Administrators Association (NASAA)","companyUrl":"https://www.linkedin.com/company/75855/","jobTitle":"General Counsel","dateRange":"Oct 2015 – Present","location":"Washington, DC","description":null},{"companyName":"North American Securities Administrators Association (NASAA)","companyUrl":"https://www.linkedin.com/company/75855/","jobTitle":"Legal Department (see below for positions)","dateRange":"Apr 2012 – Oct
```

I am trying to read each element of the list into for loop and reading the list elements into dictionary keys and values.

```
Ldict={}
for i in todos:
    Ldict[i["general"]["fullName"]] = i['jobs']
```

I expect the Ldict with fullName as Keys and jobs as values so that i can convert it to a dataframe and then finally export to excel. But the error i am getting is

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-95e00e78255f> in <module>
      1 Ldict={}
      2 for i in todos:
----> 3     Ldict[i["general"]["fullName"]] = i['jobs']

KeyError: 'general'
```

Although the 'general' is present in the list.In fact

```
print(todos[0]['general']['fullName'])
```

gives me output as

```
A. Valerie Mirko
```

Comment: So `todos[0]` has a `"general"` key. Does _every_ entry in `todos` have a `"general"` key?

Answer (score 0):

Please check to make sure that *every* item in your **entire** list has the attribute "general".

If the value exists, then it wouldn't throw a KeyError

Comment: It's a KeyError not a ValueError; and it's a key, not an attribute.

Comment: Ah sorry I'm sometimes stupid like that >_<... Thanks for catching that!